# Implementing markov Chain Example - java

Tags: java, algorithm, hidden-markov-models, markov-chains

There are plenty of Markov Chain examples for text simulations, however for a state change (for ex weather change based on probability over time) I couldn't find any examples. For ex, lets say

```
Sunny --> Sunny = probability is 0.8
Sunny --> Rainy = probability is 0.2
```

what I am looking is a way to write an algorithm which will display the current weather till n no of steps.

for e.g:  `f(3) => S,S,R`

I guess what I am really finding it difficult is how to put the randomness to the algorithm.

[This](https://gist.github.com/veryphatic/3190969) algorithm generate a sentence based on the probability of given words in a phrase, but I am unable to map it into my requirement.( I am not good in maths)

And pls let me know how can I extend the algorithm, for ex 
if the probability of a sunny day with high humidity is 0.3, the function should produce something like

```
 f(4) -> [S,Low Hu],[S, Low Hu],[R,High Hu] etc..
```

<s>Please let me know whether this approach is good for my requirement.</s>
pseudo code would be enough.

Comment: pls leave a comment if you are down voting something, so the person who ask the question know why he got down voted.

Comment: 0.8 + 0.4 = 1.2...

Comment: corrected. my bad :(

Comment: What exactly are you looking to have answered here? If your question is about what's the best approach, that heads into opinion-based territory which is off-topic. You also seem to have multiple questions (though i'm not sure) and that leads into being too broad.

Comment: I guess I can create the transition matrix, but what I am finding it difficult is how to get the randomness in place. What I try to say is I want to get the result as the output instead of the probability after n no of steps.

Comment: Isn't this just as simple as repeatedly looking at the previous value and generating the next value based on that? It's hard to see exactly which part of this you're stuck with. If you want to do this in a generic way, it's a bit harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mockNeat.probabilities()`](https://www.mockneat.com/docs/#probabilities) method from the library with the same name, if you don't want to implement the same functionality by yourself. Or you can take a look on how it's implemented.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I got confused, for my requirement I never need to implement a markov chain, All I had to do is to generate a random number between 0 and 1 and consider the option based on the generated number. So I did that. However the answer you provided(the util) does exactly that. Thank you and +1 for not only giving me a correct answer but also trying to understand what I was asking about.  Stackoverflow need more ppl like you.